# How to correctly understand stack race provided by Google play console crash report

Tags: java, android, stack-trace, google-play-console, crash-reports

I'm getting crash details as following from the Google play console crash report.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.csa.bluetoothremote.MainActivity$11.onClick (MainActivity.java:62)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage (AlertController.java:37)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8506)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

But I can't figure out what is the meaning of $11 in MainActivity$11 and 62 of (MainActivity.java:62) in the 2nd line above. I thought 62 means a line number. But in my code there is some imports in line number 62. So what are the meaning of those numbers. I want to know how to correctly map these details in my source code and find where is the error exactly.

The problem is at some where here as I guess. But I want to know exact place

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_widget_dialog, null);
        final RelativeLayout mainViewLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.mainViewLayout);
        ImageButton btnIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_widget_icon);
        final ImageButton mainImgBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.mainImgBtn);
        Button btnColor = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_widget_color);
        final Button mainTxtBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.mainTxtBtn);
        final EditText txtId = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_widget_id);
        final EditText txtDown = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_down);
        final EditText txtUp = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_up);
        final Switch swchIsTgl = view.findViewById(R.id.swch_isTgl);

        btnColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectColor(values, v, mainImgBtn, mainTxtBtn, mainViewLayout);
            }
        });

        btnIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectIcon(values, v, mainImgBtn, mainTxtBtn, mainViewLayout);
            }
        }); 

        AlertDialog.Builder dBld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        dBld.setView(view);
       

        dBld.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ...
            }
        });


        dBld.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        AlertDialog dlg = dBld.create();
        dlg.show();
```

Comment: Please provide your code on MainActivity

Comment: $11 refers to an inner class, presumably your click handler. Look at the line number.

Comment: @Rustam sorry my MainActivty has about 1800+ lines. But I guess the problem is at specific point. I will update my question with that part. But the line numbers are not equal to that. line no 62 contains some library imports.

Comment: @tgdavies now I figure out my proguard rules does not keep lines as it is after release. So  now how can I found the place mention here as line no 62. Are there any special tool to do that

Comment: Run without proguard while you're developing? Or is this from a customer? You might need to figure out which class is $11

Comment: @tgdavies this stack trace from a customer as I mention I got it from play console crash report. I don't face this crash while testing in any of my devices. So I can't find the issue

Comment: it definitely has to do with the Alert , please check your button inside on your custom Alert class and check alert lifecycle , may be you call postive/negative button but alert was reset her state as "null" , then check proguard also

Comment: @Rustam thank you for the comment. Could you please explain more about "alert was reset her state" I can't figure out how it will be reset.

Comment: try move alert object as local then init him on method onCreate()

Comment: @Rustam ok I'll try but the problem is it never crashes on any of my devices. I have tested it on many devices. This stack trace form the PlaySotre crash reports. Anyway I'll try that. Thanks